# What technique can I best use to monitor system health status of camera system?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

**Introduction**: I have a camera system (6 cameras) on basis of which a third party system performs classification and segmentation of images. This is used to monitor product quality of a products with different properties.

**Problem**:The cameras are not frequently/well maintained and are in a dirty area - they often get dirty, get turned off, lightning condition changes, get hit/turned and that has a detrimental effect on classification accuracy.

**Question**: I want to perform continuous system health monitoring: when are my cameras clean/functioning all right, and when are they not. That way I can perform timely maintenance actions. What technique can I best use to to that?

**Assumptions**:

- I can not provide manual monitoring of the system health - it has to be automated
- The third party system can not be altered
- Camera images & classification stats are available

**Relevance**: I was thinking in the direction of using machine learning (preferably without a human in the loop) to perform an assessment of system health. Also I think this is a common problem in computer vision systems (especially in autonomous driving), therefor I thought this to be the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a fixed object in the field of vision? If so, this could be used. Compare the quality of the current image with the best quality obtainable.